# How to reduce the speed of a sound using sound_play from Ros?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, ros

i am working on a project(Text to speech using Sound_play) in a state machine in ros and i am almost done. i just have this problem that the voice reads the text very fast. i will love it to be slower, i have searched everywhere to no avail. Will be glad if anyone can help.